# Configure android choose an action of file upload

Tags: android

I am currently developing a web based system using asp.net. the user would used a company provided phone which is android phone equipped with an camera application call solocator.

The problem is. I want to be able to allow the user to directly upload a photo from the application itself. is there anyway to configure android to allow user to select solocator when they click on the upload button.

Currently picture below is showing the available option when the user choose upload a file.

[image]

i want the solocator application be available on the list

Comment: cannot just configure android to include the solocator into the option list??

Comment: Where exactly is the upload button that you're using?  Is it in the solocator app?

Comment: you can try here http://www.ipeninsula.com.my/upload.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no solution for this question as the solocator itself is not an camera application. If the solocator is categorised as camera application. it would be there.

the answer is provided by the solocator team itself..

sorry for all the trouble.